# audio recorder not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, audio-recording

I installed audio recorder following [this](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/08/13/install-audio-recorder-ubuntu-16-04-16-10/) tutorial.

Installation went well, but when I start recording my own voice and save the file, I open the audio file but I do not hear anything.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you play other sounds like say music or a podcast? This may seem silly but it sort of halves the number of potential problems.

Comment: @ianorlin Yes, I play music files, watch Youtube videos and listen to online radio stations normally. Except when I register my own voice, I do not hear anything.